# Inverse Dict in Python

Tags: python, data-structures, dictionary

I am trying to create a new dict using a list of values of an existing dict as individual keys.

So for example:

```
dict1 = dict({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[1,2,3,4], 'c':[1,2]})
```

and I would like to obtain:

```
dict2 = dict({1:['a','b','c'], 2:['a','b','c'], 3:['a','b'], 4:['b']})
```

So far, I've not been able to do this in a very clean way. Any suggestions?

Comment: out of curiosity: why do you need that?

Comment: This needs to be accessible in both directions as it'll happen a lot, and it needs to be serialisable, ideally without introducing more classes that would need importing if it was used in a separate module due to a complexity of the way the particular system i'm working with does things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Python 2.5 or above, use the [`defaultdict` class from the `collections`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) module; a `defaultdict` automatically creates values on the first access to a missing key, so you can use that here to create the lists for `dict2`, like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict1 = dict({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[1,2,3,4], 'c':[1,2]})
dict2 = defaultdict(list)
for key, values in dict1.items():
    for value in values:
        # The list for dict2[value] is created automatically
        dict2[value].append(key)
```

Note that the lists in dict2 will not be in any particular order, as a dictionaries do not order their key-value pairs.

If you want an ordinary dict out at the end that will raise a `KeyError` for missing keys, just use `dict2 = dict(dict2)` after the above.

Comment: You don't need a defaultdict for that simple thing. Just replace the append line to:
dict2.setdefault(value, []).append(key)

Comment: You don't ever "need" a default dict. It just makes code simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that you don't need the `dict` in your examples: the `{}` syntax gives you a dict:

```
dict1 = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[1,2,3,4], 'c':[1,2]}
```

Answer (score -3):

Other way:

```
dict2={}
[[ (dict2.setdefault(i,[]) or 1) and (dict2[i].append(x)) for i in y ] for (x,y) in dict1.items()]
```

Comment: -1 for a hideous abuse of Python: (1) List comprehensions should not have side-effects (2) Tortured boolean logic to achieve "a then b"

Comment: I really wish I could downvote this twice, just to make the point. Please put it out of its misery.